# Shell Script - Doesn't access contents of variables

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I'm writing a Shell Script and an unexpected error (that I never saw before) appears.

The code is something like this:

```
 num=1

 case $line in
    *.mp3*)
    s$num=$total_seconds; # $total_seconds is a variable with numbers like: 11.11
    a$num=$file;
    num=$(($num + 1));
    ;;
 esac
```

If I try to see the contents of these variables it doesn't show anything.

```
echo $s1 $a1
echo $s2 $a2
```

or even:

```
for ((i=1; i<=$num; i++))
do
  echo $s$i $a$i
done
```

Comment: Why are you not using arrays?

Comment: change the shebang to `/bin/bash -x` and look at the output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bash` only recognizes a variable assignment if the LHS is a literal, not an expression. While you could modify your code slightly to have such dynamically generated variable names:

```
num=1

case $line in
  *.mp3*)
  declare s$num=$total_seconds; # $total_seconds is a variable with numbers like: 11.11
  declare a$num=$file;
  num=$(($num + 1));
  ;;
esac
```

a better idea is to use an array as suggested by kojiro.

To access them dynamically, you'll need to use indirect expansion:

```
num=1
var="s$num"
echo ${!var}  # var must be the name of a variable, not any other more complex expression
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're OK with using bash (or any shell that supports arrays), then use arrays:

```
num=1
declare -a s
declare -a a
case $line in
    *.mp3*)
        s[num]=$total_seconds # $total_seconds is a variable with numbers like: 11.11
        a[num++]=$file
        ;;
esac
```

If you want something POSIXly strict, then things get tougher. I don't want to make any suggestions about that without knowing more about your code.

Aside: `$total_seconds` is a variable with *strings* like 11.11. These shells don't support floating point numbers.